# Is docker healthcheck supported in pycharm 2017.1

Tags: pycharm, docker-compose

I have a problem running pycharm with docker-compose.
I have Django inside of an container and postgres inside another container.

The strange thing is: I just get the following error when using pycharm debug mode (also when I normally run through pycharm)

> Is the server running on host "db" (127.0.53.53) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

When I run it in the command line with "docker-compose up" everything is fine.

My pycharm version and os info:

```
PyCharm 2017.1
Build #PY-171.3780.115, built on March 24, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b13 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.3
```

I'm not sure how pycharm works with docker. Does it have its own version?

My docker-compose version information:

```
docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245
docker-py version: 2.2.0
CPython version: 2.7.10
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
 version: '2.1'
 services:
   db:
     image: postgres
     restart: always
     ports:
      - "5432:5432"
     healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
      retries: 3
      timeout: 10s
      interval: 3s


   web:
     build: .
     restart: always
     command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
     volumes:
       - .:/code
     ports:
       - "8000:8000"
     depends_on:
       db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

I guess its the healthcheck which is not supported. The purpose of healthcheck is, that the web image waits until postgres is really successfully started. If I skip this I'll get the same error as in pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem using `docker-compose.yml` with Pycharm 2017.3 recently where the error I was getting appeared to be related to the healthcheck config I had in my `docker-compose` file

```
Can not deserialize insurance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain:
com.intellij.docker.compose.configuration.beans.v2.DockerComposeConfigurationV2["services"]->java.utillInkedHashMap["web"]->com.intellij.docker.compose.configuration.beans.v2.DockerComposeServiceV2["depends_on"])
```

I switched from using the healthcheck config to using the [waisbrot/wait](https://hub.docker.com/r/waisbrot/wait/) docker image to ensure Postgres was ready, configured as below for your example:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"

web:
  build: .
  restart: always
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  depends_on:
    - db

wait:
  image: waisbrot/wait
  links:
    - db
  environment:
    - TARGETS=db:5432
```

Hope this helps.

I've since had some issues using `waisbrot/wait` and have changed to [control startup order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) method in my `docker-compose` file as below and found this works as expected on Pycharm 2017.3 (OSX) and also ensures the database service is available and ready to use by the `web` container.  (This has also been tested to work when building in Jenkins which is where I experienced problems with the `waisbrot/wait` method).

You need to ensure you use the correct version of the script for your `web` container, either `bash` or `sh` (Alpine uses `sh`).

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"

web:
  build: .
  restart: always
  command: ./wait-for.sh db:5432 -- python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  depends_on:
    - db
```